How to add a Related Contact to a Contact in Guidewire Contact Manager via API?
The question is basically in the title.  I looked at the Contact API and there doesn't seem to be a reference to "Related Contacts" in it.  For those with GW documentation access, this is where I have been directed to look based on searches: https://docs.guidewire.com/cloud/pc/202407/cloudapicm/cloudAPI/topics/landing_Cloud-API-ContactManager.html

The coverage of the Cloud API content is not comprehensive to all content of the InsuranceSuite applications.  API coverage is continually expanding over time.  For this type of question please open a case with Guidewire support to get more information and to register your implementations interest/need for a particular API endpoint.

To add onto Marty's answer. I would also expect ContactManager to get the least amount of attention for new Cloud API features from GW Product Development. So you can certainly open a case and otherwise raise your concern for this feature, but I would be realistic on how quickly a feature like this might be implemented by Guidewire.

I can't speak to any specifics, and to some extent Steve may have a point, but I will say that the footprint of the Cloud APIs expand with every release (just review release notes to confirm!).  But certainly the main apps - CC, PC, and BC - are the primary targets.  The assumption is that most references to Contact content is in the scope of those applications.  However Vendors (for CC) are the exception to that rule and there are certainly use cases for vendor management that require API content directly on CM.  Again, open a case and explicitly request escalation as a feature request!

Definitely agree with Marty that you should open a case and see what happens. My earlier comment was simply an opinion that this specific use case for ContactManager might not get prioritized very highly, so you may need to solve this yourself if this functionality is needed immediately. Certainly open a case and see what Guidewire says though.

If your implementation cannot find a workaround and needs to implement prior to the official implementation, you have the option of exposing the Entity in a custom API.
Entities  that are not currently exposed, can be exposed in a custom endpoint and created using the Rest Endpoint Generator (REG).  Of course, when support is implemented, the API usage should be converted to the official API's.
REG is fairly easy to use, most of the structure is generated.  The code is generated with markers of where the developer needs to add specifics.  The documentation is here, login required
The new API will need to be registered with GW Cloud in order to be accessed.  Documentation for registering your endpoint is here, login required
